# open wordpress which is in a folder as root

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I installed wordpress in a folder inside `public_html/`, getting

DIR `public_html/wordpress`

URL `https://www.website.com/wordpress`

I would like to be able to access the site without the `/wordpress` directory, leaving only `https://www.website.com/`

And when you need to access the dashboard `https://www.website.com/wp-admin`

I tried this procedure, but it doesn't work. What is the correct way?

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Create a Virtual Host, But with Wordpress changing the domain name is a pain as it stores it in the database

Comment: use domain aliases or just move your wordpress files to public_html folder

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:

- you are working directly with a server, this is, you have full access and root or related privileges, a virtual machine or any IaaS cloud solution,
- Apache as the web server,
- you are working on Linux,
- we are not talking about a site that is being migrated from a whole different place to here, this is, its DB has the basics of a brand new site ...

... then adjust the `DocumentRoot` of its *VirtualHost* to (the absolute path) of `.../public_html/wordpress` *(this should be the solution under this scenario)*.

But if you don't have access to the *VirtualHost* configuration file, then you need to check with your provider how to do this adjustment.

And if we are talking about a site that is being migrated from another server configuration, you might also check the DB for the right domain values in the `wp_options` and `wp_posts` tables.